Oscillations of Lagrange interpolation polynomials
Let $I = [a,b]$ be a real closed interval. Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $x_i = a+i\frac{(b-a)}{n}$ for $i=0,...,n$. Let $p_j(x)$ be the Lagrange interpolating polynomial of the $n+1$ points of coordinates $(x_i, \delta_{ij})$. The polynomial $p_j(x)$  behaves well but there exists a certain $d$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-x_j| >d$ the values of $p_j(x)$ start to oscillate a lot. Is it possible to express $d$ as a function of $a$, $b$ and $n$?

The parameters $a$ and $b-a$ only determine horizontal shift and horizontal scaling, so we can limit ourselves to the case where $a=0$ and $b=1.$
The Lagrange polynomial is then
$$p_j(x)=\prod_{i\neq j}\frac{x-\frac i n}{\frac j n-\frac i n}$$
The rest depends a little on how you define "oscillating a lot", but one simple measure is the derivative of $p_j$ at its first zero $x=0$ (assuming $j>0$):
$$p'_j(0)=n\frac{\sum_{k\neq j}\prod_{i\neq j,k}(0-i)}{\prod_{i\neq j}(j-i)}
=\frac{(-)^jn.n!}{j.j!(n-j)!}$$
